# How to programatically create an animated gif file that cannot autoplay

Tags: gif, autoplay

Is it possible to programatically create a gif file that can't be auto played in a browser (desktop\mobile) and in common messaging applications?

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps you!

Open the Animated gif in Photoshop.

```
Go to the Window tab and select timeline(if the timeline is not already open).

At the bottom of the timeline panel, you will find an option, which says "Forever". Change that to "Once".

Go to File> Export> Export for Web and save it as a gif.
```

Comment: I want to create the file programatically (updated the question). I also don't want it to autoplay even once.